# Hash grouped_by method to iterate through with a number as a key

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out how many times each URL shows up in this hash. I want to eventually find the URL with the highest number of occurrences.

```
urls = [
  {'url' => 'yahoo.com/blog'},
  {'url' => 'yahoo.com/info'},
  {'url' => 'yahoo.com/blog'}
]
```

I have this so far:

```
urls.group_by {|hash| hash.values}
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Are you receiving that hash from somewhere, or are you generating it? If you're generating it, then perhaps you should look at the code that does that, and not bother making an array of hashes, and instead make a simple array. That would simplify the problem.

Comment: Which hash? You have several hashes. And it seems that each hash has a single url.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idiom that I've seen a lot for counting things in an array:

```
urls = [{'url' => 'yahoo.com/blog'}, {'url' => 'yahoo.com/info'}, {'url' => 'yahoo.com/blog'}]

urls.each.with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|url, h| h[url['url']] += 1 }
#=> {"yahoo.com/blog"=>2, "yahoo.com/info"=>1}
```

**Edit**

If you insist on using `Hash#group_by`, you can do this, although it is less efficient:

```
urls.group_by {|hash| hash.values }.map {|k, v| [k.first, v.length] }.to_h
```

Comment: Did you mean `each_with_object`? `each.with_object` is fine, just unusual.

Answer (score 1):

I like using `inject` with an accumulator for this kind of thing:

```
2.1.2 :011 > urls = [{'url' => 'yahoo.com/blog'}, {'url' => 'yahoo.com/info'}, {'url' => 'yahoo.com/blog'}]
 => [{"url"=>"yahoo.com/blog"}, {"url"=>"yahoo.com/info"}, {"url"=>"yahoo.com/blog"}]
2.1.2 :012 > urls.map{ |u| u['url'] }.inject({}){ |acc,url|
2.1.2 :013 >     acc[url] ||= 0
2.1.2 :014?>   acc[url] += 1
2.1.2 :015?>   acc
2.1.2 :016?>   }
 => {"yahoo.com/blog"=>2, "yahoo.com/info"=>1}
```

Comment: Although, Adrian's answer, `each.with_object`, is somewhat more elegant

Comment: IMHO it's better to use `inject` when the return value of the block changes -- `acc` is always the same object in your code every time the block is run

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
urls.flat_map(&:values)
    .group_by { |u| u }
    .map { |u,us| [u, us.size ] }
    .max_by(&:last)
  #=> ["yahoo.com/blog", 2]
```

Here are the steps:

```
a = urls.flat_map(&:values)
  #=> ["yahoo.com/blog", "yahoo.com/info", "yahoo.com/blog"] 
b = a.group_by { |u| u }
  #=> {"yahoo.com/blog"=>["yahoo.com/blog", "yahoo.com/blog"],
  #    "yahoo.com/info"=>["yahoo.com/info"]} 
c = b.map { |u,us| [u, us.size ] }
  #=> [["yahoo.com/blog", 2], ["yahoo.com/info", 1]] 
c.max_by(&:last)
  #=> ["yahoo.com/blog", 2]
```

Another way:

```
urls.each_with_object({}) { |u,h| h.update({ u['url']=>1 }) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
    .max_by { |_,v| v }
  # => ["yahoo.com/blog", 2]
```